# Asynchronous CUDA transfer calls not behaving asynchronously

Tags: asynchronous, cuda

I am using my GPU concurrently with my CPU. When I profile memory transfers I find that the async calls in cuBLAS do not behave asynchronously.

I have code that does something like the following

```
cudaEvent_t event;
cudaEventCreate(&event);
// time-point A
cublasSetVectorAsync(n, elemSize, x, incx, y, incy, 0);
cudaEventRecord(event);
// time-point B
cudaEventSynchronize(event);
// time-point C
```

I'm using `sys/time.h` to profile (code omited for clarity). I find that the `cublasSetVectorAsync` call dominates the time as though it were behaving synchronously. I.e. the duration A-B is much longer than the duration B-C and increases as I increase the size of the transfer.

What are possible reasons for this? Is there some environment variable I need to set somewhere or an updated driver that I need to use?

I'm using a GeForce GTX 285 with Cuda compilation tools, release 4.1, V0.2.1221

Comment: Are you sure that passing in a null stream doesn't make the operation synchronous?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson I checked this out and no, 0 is the default stream. It should still be asynchronous. Section 3.2.5.5.2 of the CUDA C Programming guide.

Comment: Is this your real code?  You don't have any thing here for cublasSetVectorAsync to overlap.  All you do is call an async function, and then synchronize it (`cudaEventSynchronize`). That's not even mentioning the fact that you are doing everything in the default stream, within which everything is synchronous except for kernel launches (relative to calling host thread).  There are no kernel launches in the code you posted.

Comment: @harrism My real code is more complex than this. This is the minimum example I could think of that clearly demonstrates the problem. I'm only interested in asynchronicity between Host and Device so I don't think that streams are an issue. I agree that this code does not test concurrency within the GPU.

Comment: My bad. You are of course correct. Let me try to be more helpful... I will ask the CUBLAS team if this is correct, but my suggestion is that since cudaMemcpyAsync requires pinned host memory, then you need to use cudaHostAlloc to allocate the host memory that is input to cublasSetVectorAsync.  Otherwise it will have to copy to a pinned region itself (host memcpy) before copying to the device, and this would explain the behavior you are seeing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`cublasSetVectorAsync` is a thin wrapper around `cudaMemcpyAsync`. Unfortunately, in some circumstances, the name of this function is a misnomer, as explained on [this page from the CUDA reference manual](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/4_2/rel/toolkit/docs/online/sync_async.html#MemcpyAsynchronousBehavior).

Notably:

> For transfers from pageable host memory to device memory, a stream sync is performed before the copy is initiated. The function will return once the pageable buffer has been copied to the staging memory for DMA transfer to device memory, but the DMA to final destination may not have completed.

And

> For transfers from pageable host memory to device memory, host memory is copied to a staging buffer immediately (no device synchronization is performed). The function will return once the pageable buffer has been copied to the staging memory. The DMA transfer to final destination may not have completed.

So the solution to your problem is likely to just allocate `x`, your host data array, using [`cudaHostAlloc`](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/4_2/rel/toolkit/docs/online/group__CUDART__MEMORY_g15a3871f15f8c38f5b7190946845758c.html#g15a3871f15f8c38f5b7190946845758c), rather than standard `malloc` (or C++ `new`).

Alternatively, if your GPU and CUDA version support it, you can use `malloc` and then call [`cudaHostRegister`](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/4_2/rel/toolkit/docs/online/group__CUDART__MEMORY_g36b9fe28f547f28d23742e8c7cd18141.html#g36b9fe28f547f28d23742e8c7cd18141) on the `malloc`-ed pointer. Note in the documentation the condition that you must create your CUDA context with the `cudaDeviceMapHost` flag in order for `cudaHostRegister` to have any effect (see the documentation for [`cudaSetDeviceFlags`](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/4_2/rel/toolkit/docs/online/group__CUDART__DEVICE_g18074e885b4d89f5a0fe1beab589e0c8.html#g18074e885b4d89f5a0fe1beab589e0c8).

Comment: Nice answer @harrism. To make sure I understand `cudaHostAlloc` allocates to pinned memory which doesn't require a synchronous staging operation. Are there any limits to using cudaHostAlloc and pinned memory?

Comment: Thanks. That's right: the GPU can DMA directly from pinned memory, but not pageable memory. So if you use pageable host memory, the driver has to copy the data into a pinned staging buffer on the host, meaning an extra CPU-side memcpy, performance of which is CPU, system RAM, and chipset dependent. As for limits, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12439807/pinned-memory-in-cuda).

Comment: Thanks again. This is probably the most useful and complete answer I've received on SO.

Answer (score -1):

In cuBLAS/cuSPARSE, things take place in stream 0 if you don't specify a different stream. To specify a stream, you have to use cublasSetStream (see cuBLAS documentation).

Comment: My understanding is that streams are for concurrency within the GPU. I believe that even I put everything on stream 0 that GPU-CPU interactions will still be concurrent and GPU kernel calls will not block the CPU. Is my understanding incorrect?

Comment: cuBlasSetVector does not call any CUDA kernels.  It just calls cudaMemcpyAsync, which is synchronous if it is called on stream zero, the default stream.

Comment: @harrism "`cudaMemcpyAsync()` is asynchronous with respect to the host, so the call may return before the copy is complete.... The copy can optionally be associated to a stream ... [if] the stream is non-zero, the copy may overlap with operations in other streams. " --CUDA Developer Documentation http://goo.gl/fXDl8  I'm not interested in concurrency within the GPU. I'm only interested in Host-Device concurrency.

Comment: Correct. See my "my bad" comment on your question.