# Difference between Constant Memory & Texture Memory & Pinned Memory in CUDA

Tags: c++, cuda, gpu

I am learning to work with GPUs using C++ CUDA, and I could not find a clear answer to a question. Could you please explain briefly the difference between:

1. Constant Memory
2. Texture Memory
3. Pinned Memory

I need a small amount of memory that is accessible by all kernels. Is the best approach is using constant memory?

Comment: This covers 1) and 2): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8306967/constant-memory-vs-texture-memory-vs-global-memory-in-cuda?rq=1

Comment: This somewhat covers 3): [Pinned memory in CUDA](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12439807/10107454).
If the data is not modified by the kernels, constant memory seems like a good idea.